# Firebase Database Query

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

here i am retrieving `senderId` as `sID` and `recieverId` as `rID`. but after retrieving i failed to access these two id's  while concatenation. How can i access these two id's outside this query. Please help.

**Here is code**

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("cUsers");                                  
ref.orderByChild("email").equalTo(senderEmail).on("child_added", function (snapshot){
      var sID = snapshot.val().uid;
      alert(sID);
    });
                                    ref.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
      var rID = snapshot.val().uid;
      alert(rID);
    });

var chatUsers=sID+"_"+rID;
```

Comment: What error are you getting? If its a undefined error is because you are creating the variables inside the functions scope and trying to use them outside of it, try creating the variables before the functions and just set their values inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
var sID = '';
var rID = '';

var ref = firebase.database().ref("cUsers");                                  
ref.orderByChild("email").equalTo(senderEmail).on("child_added", function (snapshot){
    sID = snapshot.val().uid;
    alert(sID);
});
ref.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
    rID = snapshot.val().uid;
    alert(rID);
});

var chatUsers=sID+"_"+rID;
```

Comment: No . it is getting undefined_undefined.

Comment: But i want that if sID=2 and rID=1 .so chatUsers should get 2_1.

Comment: I have defined sID and rID outside the function .but these two doesnot get the value from queries . and they get defined values outside of function.

Comment: please help further

Comment: I mean, the queries are, indeed, getting the values?

Comment: Can you show me the whole context of that function? Are you using it inside an object, another function or something?